# How to show header HTML formatting in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, html, intellij-idea, formatting, ide

For example in a header file I often see HTML markdown tags such as `<br> or <p>` but I'm unsure as how to go about actually properly displaying said formatting.

Here's an example:

[image: Text formatting example]

Comment: What do you mean by "displaying"? Are you writing an IDE? What is the context of your question?  We need a lot more context in order to know what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display the formatted Javadoc output in IntelliJ use `View > Quick Documentation`.

Here's an example screenshot:

[image]

This action can also be accessed via a keyboard shortcut, to see which combination of keystrokes is bound to this action just have a look under `Preferences > Keymap` ...

[image]

Comment: This is what I was referring to. I did not know that the formatting typically found in a pre-made class is intended for Quick Documentation. I thought there was a way to show it as an entire HTML-like page.